# Is there way to get name of coroutine function?

Tags: c++, trace, coroutine, c++-coroutine

When I declare coroutine in C++ I use simple function body:

```
TTask<float> CoroFunc()
{
  co_await Wait(1.0);
  co_return 1.0;
}
```

My goal is write coroutine tracer to detect when each coroutine started, finished and resumed. The tracer must also receive name of coroutine function (CoroFunc).

The constructor of TTask receives coroutine_handle when it constructed. I have no idea how to retrieve function name information from handle. I know only macro `__FUNCTION__` that can return function name, but it is not usable inside `CoroFunc` - I can't pass it to TTask. And it would be better to avoid any manual macro calls. If it happend automatically in TTask implementation it would be great. Is that possible?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location

Comment: @MarekR  do you mean such code `promise_type(std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) : loc(loc) {   std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << " called for " << loc.function_name() << std::endl; }`  or something else, something better? Anyway - maybe you can provide an answer so I can upvote...